# multi row update troubles mysql

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to replace column data in single table.

there's table 'catalog_category_product' :

'position','old_position','category_id','product_id'.

i want to replace  'old_position' with 'position' only if category_id = 9
heres my query:

```
UPDATE catalog_category_product
SET catalog_category_product.old_position = 

( 
 select position
  FROM (select * from catalog_category_product) AS m2
WHERE category_id = 110
) 
WHERE category_id = 9`
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Update catalog_category_product as c1, catalog_category_product as c2 set c1.old_position = c2.position where c2.category_id = 110 and c1.category_id = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE catalog_category_product AS t1 INNER JOIN catalog_category_product AS t2 
          ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
          SET t1.old_position = t2.position
          WHERE t1.category_id = {{$parentCategory}} AND t2.category_id  = {{$childCategory}
```

it worked for me